# How to use sessions with django piston auth?

Tags: django, session, django-piston

The problem is that I want to store authentication in a cookie that I can present to django piston rather than requiring user/password to be typed in each time (without hardcoding or storing the user/pass combo somewhere on disk).  I was hoping to accomplish this with cookies like someone would without the piston API.  Am I missing something?

Django Piston doesn't seem to care about session cookies at all?

Or can someone suggest a good alternative?  Maybe I shouldn't use Piston?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://yml-blog.blogspot.com/2009/10/django-piston-authentication-against.html

Comment: thanks for the link, that looks very helpful and more or less exactly what I was looking for

Comment: It would also seem that piston separates itself from the "auth" system intentionally, which is nice and not so nice (because it doesnt work out of the "box")... but I understand the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep a user logged in after they authenticate, Django's built in Sessions do that for you.  You can change how long the session lasts by changing the [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age) setting.  This will also change how long the sessions persist in your database (if you are using a database backend).

Comment: I may have dug myself into too deep of a hole.  I'm currently using sessions, but it appears that Piston does not seem to respect sessions.  I may have to defer this to Piston directly.  Thanks though.

Comment: @xyld Are you saying that request.session / request.user are not correct for the piston requests you're getting?